# SQL: How can I delete a row when a unix time is reached?

Tags: mysql, sql, unix, row

Sorry, don't really know much about this stuff!

I have a table with a few columns, one of them is called 'expirationday' and every row has its unix timestamp for this column.

I would like to know, if at all possible, how to delete a row when the time in the 'expirationday' column (for that row) is reached.

Please note that it does not need to delete rows accurately to the second, a couple of hours is fine.

Comment: You could run a cron job (or similar) which would query the database every few hours and delete any rows with a timestamp < now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

script.sh

Create a shell script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

mysql --user=[username] --password=[password] --database=[db name] --execute="DELETE FROM tbl_name WHERE expiration_date < NOW()
```

Create a cron job that executes the (it will run every 30 min)

type

```
crontab -e
```

Add:

```
0,30 * * * * /path/script.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

It's worth looking at the [MySQL event scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html). You could schedule a job to run for example every half hour.

It could then call a DELETE statement directly or to call a [MySQL Function or Procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html).

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE 
    EVENT `deleteExpire` 
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR STARTS '2015-01-01 00:00:00' 
    DO BEGIN

        DELETE FROM mytable
              WHERE expirationday < UNIX_TIMESTAMP();

    END */$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Also see this for [more example usage](http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/).